# PHP consonants in string changing

Tags: php, string

I need help with PHP. I guess its easy but I'm still learning. Couldn't find anything on this.

I want the string a user types, like: `Dennis`. To get the result: `dod-e-non-non-i-sos`.

So, a consonant like: `g` should become `gog`.

```
consonants = array("b", "c", 
"d", "f", "g", "h", "j", "k", "l", "m",
"n", "p" , "q" , "r" , "s" , "t" , "v" , "x" , "z");
```

Comment: So you couldn't find the [PHP Docs page for str_replace()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)?

Answer (score 2):

Very efficient with regular expressions:

```
$string = preg_replace('/[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz]/i', '$0o$0', $string);
```

See http://regular-expressions.info for a tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

You have to loop on each consonnant, and do a str_replace.

```
$myString = "dennis";
foreach(consonants as $consonant) {
    $myString = str_replace($consonant, $consonant."o".$consonant, $myString);
}
```

So you replace each "consonant" with consonant + o + consonant
The problem is with cap letters, you should add them to $consonnants

Comment: @user3071878 You're welcome. Please accept answer if it solves the problem.

Comment: This works, but is very inefficient. See deceze answer for a correct way to solve the issue.